# Can't access static resources

Tags: spring-boot

Sorry if I'm doing something wrong, but I have no spring-security dependencies in my classpath, but I can't access static resources.

BTW it works fine with the versions of spring boot lower than 2.0.0.M4.

Spring boot v2.0.0.M5

**Update:**

The problem was resolved somehow. I really don't know what's happened. Perhaps, the problem was in Gradle, I did `gradle --stop`, then switched Spring Boot version back to 2.0.0.M5 and build like this `gradle --rerun-tasks --no-daemon --refresh-dependencies clean build`.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Can you please explain what you need and share some code? Read following article to understand how to ask questions properly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's a bit vague. Perhaps you can share a sample that reproduces what you're seeing?